# How can I render the GUI when all the data is available?

Tags: redux, react-redux, reactjs, jsx

everything in my if statement is data i'm grabbing from an API pretty much.. if I don't put this if-statement to check if the available is there.. i get an error saying the props is undefined.. if i put the if statement for to check first that the data is correct.. then it does not render.

i know the data is correct because if i put a "console.log('something')" in the renderWhenDataisAvail and save in my IDE, it causes it to re-render for some reason and i see the GUI that i'm hoping to see

EDIT: i put a console.log of the state and the this.logicLayers and this.logicLayersById and everytthing in the state loads eventually but the 'this.logicLayers' and 'this.logicLayersById' variables load to slow and my console shows them as undefined at first.. but if i console log it 2 seconds later it's loaded properly.  but it's as if the render gives up trying to render after a few tries and doesn't wait long enough?

```
renderWhenDataIsAvail() {
    if (this.state.pagesById && this.state.graphicLayersById && this.logicLayers && this.logicLayersById && this.state.pages && this.subComps) {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.graphicLayers.map((id) =>
            <GraphicLayer
              key={id}
              addLayerClick={this.addLayerClick}
              addPageClick={this.addPageClick}
              graphicLayer={this.state.graphicLayersById[id]}
              logicLayers={this.logicLayers}
              logicLayersById={this.logicLayersById}
              pages={this.state.pages}
              pagesById={this.state.pagesById}
              subComps={this.subComps} />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }


render() {
    console.log(this.state);  // these load eventually
    console.log(this.logicLayers);  // loads eventually but too slow?
    console.log(this.logicLayersById);  // loads eventually but too slow?

    return (      
      <div>
        {this.renderWhenDataIsAvail()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, render will not wait for `this.logicLayersById` and `this.logicLayers` to load at the time of checking, its only if you change the state that rerender occurs and the values are checked again and your page will get updated since the values are there

Try to save the values in state.

```
renderWhenDataIsAvail() {
    if (this.state.pagesById && this.state.graphicLayersById && this.state.logicLayers && this.state.logicLayersById && this.state.pages && this.subComps) {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.graphicLayers.map((id) =>
            <GraphicLayer
              key={id}
              addLayerClick={this.addLayerClick}
              addPageClick={this.addPageClick}
              graphicLayer={this.state.graphicLayersById[id]}
              logicLayers={this.logicLayers}
              logicLayersById={this.logicLayersById}
              pages={this.state.pages}
              pagesById={this.state.pagesById}
              subComps={this.subComps} />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }


render() {
    console.log(this.state);  // these load eventually
    console.log(this.logicLayers);  // loads eventually but too slow?
    console.log(this.logicLayersById);  // loads eventually but too slow?

    return (      
      <div>
        {this.renderWhenDataIsAvail()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: ahhhh ok i think this makes sense let me try

Comment: Glad to have helped :)